# Xamarin - When try to deploy the build never ending

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin.ios

I'm developing xamarin application for both IOS and Androaid, when I'm try to publish the Ios appliaction to my iphone the build never ends and no error appear, I tring to upgrade my Xcode but this didn't help. 
When I'm using the IOS simulator everything works fine, the build ends and the app run as expected. I tried all the solutions that I found on the internet but none of them help.

Is anybody encounter this problem and have solution for this issue??
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XU8cO.png)

Comment: What is the Xamarin output showing?  From the dropdown list where it currently says "Build", select "Xamarin" when the project builds.  Also, the logs may reveal what's going on, from the Visual Studios menu bar, Help->Xamarin->Open Logs.  I suspect a provisioning issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Xamarin frameworks are updated as latest stable version on both of Visual Studio and MacOs?
- Did you accept Apple New License Agreement on your apple account?

You can check logs. (Help->Xamarin->Open Logs)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Xamarin is update in both of VS and MacOs, I'm working with virtual machine that I install on it MacOs.  Yesterday I didn't stop the build and after something like 3 hours the it finished and deployed to my device. But still I'm facing the problem that every build takes 1-3 hours!